# Showing that complex limit exists

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

1. $\,\lim\limits_{z\to1}\dfrac{z}{1+\overline{z}}$
2. $\,\lim\limits_{z\to 0}\dfrac{\overline{z}^2-z^2}{z}$

So in general, it is easy for me to show that a limit does not exist, one tries to find two paths  on which they are not equal. But how to show that it in fact exists? Would polar coordinates be the only possibility? Aren’t polar coordinates only for the case $(x,y) \to (0,0)$? So how to handle the case $z \to 1$ with them?

I tried to do it with polar coordinates in the second case:
(I think I need to show that it doesn’t depend on $\theta$?)

2. $\,\lim\limits_{r\to 0}\dfrac{r^2e^{-2i\theta}-r^2e^{2i \theta}}{re^{i\theta}}$

But doing l’Hôpital here, it would still depend on $\theta$?

Comment: For $z \to 1$ write $z=1+re^{i\theta}$.

Comment: The first limit is obvious and equal $1/2.$ Concerning the second limit it suffices to consider $\bar{z}^2/z.$ Then we have $|\bar{z}^2|/|z|=|z|$ so the limit is equal $0.$

Comment: @geetha290krm: thank you

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: thank you for the second, but how could I show the first? So I write $z = 1 + re^{i\theta}$, then $lim_{r \to 0}=\frac{1 + re^{i\theta}}{1 + 1 + re^{-i\theta}}$, so can I argue that letting r $\to$ 0 would lead to 1/2 no matter what $\theta$ is?

Comment: If $z\to 1,$ then $\bar{z}\to 1.$ By the arithmetic rules of the limit we get ${z\over  1+\bar{z}}\to {1\over 2}.$